# How do I convert a list into a string with spaces in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, spaces

How can I convert a list into a space-separated string in Python?

For example, I want to convert this list:

```
my_list = ["how", "are", "you"]
```

into the string `"how are you"`.

The spaces are important. I don't want to get `"howareyou"`.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

```
" ".join(my_list)
```

You need to join with a space, not an empty string.

Comment: Code like this is why I like Python.  So simple.

Comment: what if  we have string in this format `list = ['how ', 'are ', 'you ']`  then how to convert this into list.

Comment: @MuhammadTaqi then just strip the element be4 joining...
`" ".join([i.strip() for i in my_list)`

Answer (score 28):

I'll throw this in as an alternative just for the heck of it, even though it's pretty much useless when compared to `" ".join(my_list)` for strings. For non-strings (such as an array of ints) this may be better:

```
" ".join(str(item) for item in my_list)
```

Answer (score 13):

For Non String `list` we can do like this as well

```
" ".join(map(str, my_list))
```

Answer (score 5):

So in order to achieve a desired output, we should first know how the function works.

The syntax for `join()` method as described in the python documentation is as follows:

`string_name.join(iterable)`

Things to be noted:

- It returns a `string` concatenated with the elements of `iterable`. The separator between the elements being the `string_name`.
- Any non-string value in the `iterable` will raise a `TypeError`

Now, to add *white spaces*, we just need to replace the `string_name` with a `" "` or a `' '` both of them will work and place the `iterable` that we want to concatenate.

So, our function will look something like this:

```
' '.join(my_list)
```

But, what if we want to add a particular number of `white spaces` in between our elements in the `iterable` ?

We need to add this:

```
str(number*" ").join(iterable)
```

here, the `number` will be a user input.

So, for example if `number=4`.

Then, the output of `str(4*" ").join(my_list)` will be `how    are    you`, so in between every word there are 4 white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate through it to do it

```
my_list = ['how', 'are', 'you']
my_string = " "
for a in my_list:
    my_string = my_string + ' ' + a
print(my_string)
```

output is

```
 how are you
```

you can strip it to get

```
how are you
```

like this

```
my_list = ['how', 'are', 'you']
my_string = " "
for a in my_list:
    my_string = my_string + ' ' + a
print(my_string.strip())
```

Answer (score -12):

Why don't you add a space in the items of the list itself, like :
`list = ["how ", "are ", "you "]`

Comment: You have written this *answer* in a way that makes it appear to be more appropriate in the form of a comment. It would be more beneficial if you expanded this answer to explain ***why*** what you are suggesting works.

Comment: This is non-functional in a case where you do not have access to the list (e.g when generated with `input(a).split(b)`)

Comment: we should not change the internal strings because it cause us loss of space