# Convert list of strings to space-separated string

Tags: python, string, list

I am using underscores to represent the length of a unknown word. How can I print just the underscores without the brackets that represent the list?

Basically, if I have a list of the form `['_', '_', '_', '_']`, I want to print the underscores without printing them in list syntax as `"_ _ _ _"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a list into a string with spaces in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309976/how-do-i-convert-a-list-into-a-string-with-spaces-in-python)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Does this work for you

```
>>> my_dashes = ['_', '_', '_', '_']
>>> print ''.join(my_dashes)
____
>>> print ' '.join(my_dashes)
_ _ _ _
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: my_dashes = ['_', '_', '_', '_']

In [2]: str(my_dashes).translate(None, '[],\'')
Out[2]: '_ _ _ _'
```

Add an extra space in the deletechars string to put the dashes together.

Answer (score 1):

The previously-mentioned `join` solution (like in following line) is a reasonable solution:

```
print ''.join(['_', '_', '_', '_'])
____
```

But also note you can use `reduce()` to do the job:

```
print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, ['_', '_', '_', '_'])
____
```

After `import operator` you can say:

```
print reduce(operator.add, ['_', '_', '_', '_'])
____
```