# Space between strings

Tags: python, string, space

I want to print How do you like python so far? in python 3. But when I run my code there is no spaces between my strings. What should I do?

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"

print(word1+word2+word3+word4+word5+word6+word7)
```

Comment: Why do you expect spaces if there is no any space in your code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094918/convert-list-of-strings-to-space-separated-string

Comment: Put all those strings in list and join them with a delimiter of your choice. Simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of strings to space-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094918/convert-list-of-strings-to-space-separated-string)

Comment: @SauravSahu `str.format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(f'{word1} {word2} {word3} {word4} {word5} {word6} {word7}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `space` string in between or can use f-string

```
print(f'{word1} {word2} {word3} {word4} {word5} {word6} {word7}')
```

Comment: Duplicated with another earlier answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700384/248616. Thanks any way!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace **+** to **,**

```
print(word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6,word7)
```

Answer (score 0):

keep spaces in your print statments if you wanna use string + string and add space use this

```
print(word1+''+word2+''+word3+''+word4+''+word5+''+word6+''+word7)
```

But its is much easier to use f strings as shown below