# Change Sub lists into one string

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following

[1, 3, 14, 26, 59, 535] [932, 462, 97, 38, 8] [3, 3, 64, 83] [288, 279, 50] [4, 19] [716] [9, 939, 37510]

that I wish to change into

1 3 14 26 59 535 932 462 97 38 8 3 3 64 83 288 279 50 4 19 716 9 939 37510

is there any quick fix?

I have already tried joining (' '.join(str(e) for e in result))

Comment: What is your `result` here?  It's not clear here. So it's the `result` - a list of lists?

Comment: @DanielHao result is [1, 3, 14, 26, 59, 535] [932, 462, 97, 38, 8] [3, 3, 64, 83] [288, 279, 50] [4, 19] [716] [9, 939, 37510]

Comment: So it seems that you  want to `flatten` this list (of lists)?  Try itertools.chain_from iterable(result)

Comment: Is the input a list of lists?

Comment: @DanielHao Thank you! I tried flattening it, however the outside [] still remain...did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309976/how-do-i-convert-a-list-into-a-string-with-spaces-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this with a plain python comprehension

```
result = [[1, 3, 14, 26, 59, 535], [932, 462, 97, 38, 8], [3, 3, 64, 83], [288, 279, 50], [4, 19], [716], [9, 939, 37510]]

' '.join(str(n) for sublist in result for n in sublist)
```

Which will give you the string:

```
'1 3 14 26 59 535 932 462 97 38 8 3 3 64 83 288 279 50 4 19 716 9 939 37510'
```

You were almost there with your code, it just needed one more clause in the comprehension to unwind the inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `itertools` module:

```
result = [[1, 3, 14, 26, 59, 535],[932, 462, 97, 38, 8], [3, 3, 64, 83], [288, 279, 50], [4, 19], [716], [9, 939, 37510]]

from itertools import *

>print(list(chain.from_iterable(result))  # this give a flat list

# if you do want a string:
> ' '.join(str(e) for e in list(chain.from_iterable(result)))
'1 3 14 26 59 535 932 462 97 38 8 3 3 64 83 288 279 50 4 19 716 9 939 37510'
```

Comment: Edit the reply to include `string` of each number.  Please let me know if there is any question.