# how to write a function in python that accepts a list of dictionaries and returns a new list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

how to write a function in python that accepts a list of dictionaries and returns a new list of strings

```
    """
    name = [{"first":"john","last":"doe"},{"first":"jane","last":"doe"}]
    **function should accept name as the argument** 
    extract_name(name):
    
    expected o/p = # ['john Doe','jane Doe']

    """
```

I have tried these codes

```
name = [{"first":"john","last":"doe"},{"first":"jane","last":"doe"}]

def extract_names(name):
    for id in name:
        res = id.values()
        print(list(res))
extract_names(name)

"""
output
['john', 'doe']
['jane', 'doe']
"""
```

But im getting the o/p on two different lines
also I wanna know how can **map** help in this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a list into a string with spaces in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309976/how-do-i-convert-a-list-into-a-string-with-spaces-in-python)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/how-can-i-use-return-to-get-back-multiple-values-from-a-for-loop-can-i-put-th for how to add multiple results to a list instead of just printing them.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using `map()` and [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map):

```py
name = [{"first": "john", "last": "doe"}, {"first": "jane", "last": "doe"}]

out = list(map("{first} {last}".format_map, name))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['john doe', 'jane doe']
```

---

If you want a function:

```py
def fn(names):
    return list(map("{first} {last}".format_map, names))


out = fn(name)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can iterate over `dict` and use `f-string` for getting what you want.

```
# each element is dict:
name = [{"first":"john","last":"doe"},{"first":"jane","last":"doe"}]
# dict : ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ , ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def extract_name(name):
    lst = []
    for dct in name:
        lst.append(f"{dct['first']} {dct['last']}")
    return lst

res = extract_name(name)
print(res)
```

---

```
['john doe', 'jane doe']
```

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def extract_name(name):
    return [f"{dct['first']} {dct['last']}" for dct in name]
```

If you want to do with `map`.

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: f"{x['first']} {x['last']}", name))
['john doe', 'jane doe']
```